# How to write a test that has return a Task in xunit

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, mocking, xunit

This class needs to be Tested, but I do not have any idea to test a class that returns a Task

```
public async Task CreateUser(User request)
        {
            try
            {
                var _user = new User()
                {
                    FullName = request.FullName,
                    DOB = request.DOB,
                    Gender = request.Gender,
                    AddressDetail = request.AddressDetail,
                    CityId = request.CityId,
                    DistrictId = request.DistrictId,
                    WardsId = request.WardsId,
                    Phone = request.Phone,
                    Password = EncryptPassword(request.Password).GetAwaiter().GetResult().ToString(),
                    RoleId = 2,
                    Status = 1,
                };

                await _userRespository.Create(_user).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

How can I write a test that returns a Task? I really need your bits of help.

This is my Test function is below:

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task CreateUser_Task_Complete()
        {   
            //Arrange
            var mock = new Mock<IGenericService<User>>();
            var mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();

             User user = new User() { Id = 1, FullName = "abc", AddressDetail = "A", CityId = "123", DistrictId = "123", WardsId = "123", Password = "123456", Gender = "male", Phone = "0123456789", DOB = "5/5/1990", Avatar = "" }
        ;


            mock.Setup(_ => _.Create(user)).Returns(Task.FromResult(user));
            
            //Act
            var service = new UserService(mock.Object, mockConfig.Object);

            var response = service.CreateUser(user);


            //Assert
            await service.CreateUser(user);


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the Task was completed Successfully. Instead of using `await`, you can refactor to something like this;

```cs
Task createUserTask = service.CreateUser(user);
createUserTask.Wait();
Assert.True(createUserTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
```

Comment: @Viettus accept the answer and upvote it for others to find it easily